# Display a file in WPF from a SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, file

I have a questions, I don´t know if is possible. First I have saved a file in a SQL Server database from a `byte[]` (C#) to `varbinary` with this code:

```
OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
fileDialog.Title = " Seleccione la foto del Usuario";
fileDialog.ShowDialog();

if (fileDialog.FileName != null)
{
   ruta = fileDialog.FileName;
   lblnomArchivo.Content = new BitmapImage(new Uri(ruta));
   //MessageBox.Show(path);
}

public byte[] ConvertToByteArray(string path)
{
    byte[] ImageByte = null;

    try
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        //BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        //ImageByte = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);

        Byte[] data = new byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(data, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
        ImageByte = data;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

    return ImageByte;
}
```

I just want to retrieve this file in some WPF element, in a cell of a datagrid for instance can I get the name of the file and then open it....

And the file should be any file format not just image format

Comment: Are you asking how to retrieve the data from the database and display it in the application?   Also, be sure  you properly dispose of your IDisposables, such as that FileStream.

Comment: yes i wanna "to retrieve the data from the database and display it in the application"... And Excuses I´m new in WPF y i don´t know what do you mean with IDisposables,, I've never used that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know what the type of the file will be when writing the application the fallback you can use is to pass the file to the operating system and have the OS select an appropriate app to open the file.

So first get it from the database and save it (including the correct extension) then, in the app, pass the file to the OS:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filePathNameAndExtension);
```

Before doing this you could check the extension of the file name:

```
var extension = Path.GetExtension(filePathNameAndExtension).ToLower();

select(extension)
{
    case ".jpg":
    case ".png":
    case ".jpeg":
        type = Type.Image;
        break;
    case ".txt":
        type = Type.Text;
        break;
    default:
        type = Type.Unknown;
        break;
}

select(type)
{
    case Type.Unknown:
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filePathNameAndExtension);
        break;
    case Type.Image:
        myImage = new Bitmap(filePathNameAndExtension);
        break;
    .....
}
```